# How to read binary string array backwards, then convert to decimal int variable? (Without parse)

Tags: java, arrays, binary, hex, decimal

I do not understand how to code the following into the program: Read string binary array backwards. Check reversed binary array for 1 (I assume if statements). Assign bit values for each 1 in binary. Utilize math.pow to get decimal value for each 1. Add all the active bits.

My program needs to do the following: Open a text file (COMPLETED)
Text file contains:

```
 (33CDAEFFAD)  
 (032DAE01AD)  
 (196CDAEFC0)  
 (21A00D0000)  
 (100CDAEFFA)  
 (F3ABCDEFAB)  
 (29A0EDF301)  
 (3ABCDEFABC)
```

Read each hex (COMPLETED) -->
Convert hex value to binary (COMPLETED) -->
**Convert the binary value to decimal value (LOST)**

```
public static String[] hexToBinary () throws IOException //converts from 
hex to binary
{
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("RAMun3"));  

String result[] = new String[8]; //created array to hold binary values
    String bValue; 
    String x = ""; 
String y = "";
int counter = 0;      

    while (inFile.hasNextLine() && counter <= 7) //reads lines from text 
    file && stops array from                             
    going out of bounds
    {   
        String line = inFile.nextLine();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(line);
        String hex = input.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) //for loop to convert hex 
        digits to binary 
        {
            char hexC = hex.charAt(i);
        switch (hexC) 
            {
             case ('0'):
                    bValue = "0000";
                    break;   
             case ('1'):
                    bValue = "0001";
                    break;
             case ('2'):
                    bValue = "0010";
                    break;
             case ('3'):
                    bValue = "0011";
                    break;
             case ('4'):
                    bValue = "0100";
                    break;
             case ('5'):
                    bValue = "0101";
                    break;
             case ('6'):
                    bValue = "0110";
                    break;
             case ('7'):
                    bValue = "0111";
                    break;
             case ('8'):
                    bValue = "1000";
                    break;
             case ('9'):
                    bValue = "1001";
                    break;
             case ('A'):
                    bValue = "1010";
                    break;
             case ('B'):
                    bValue = "1011";
                    break;
             case ('C'):
                    bValue = "1100";
                    break;
             case ('D'):
                    bValue = "1101";
                    break;
             case ('E'):
                    bValue = "1110";
                    break;
             case ('F'):
                    bValue = "1111";
                    break;    
             default:
                    bValue = "N/A";
                    break;
                } 
    x = bValue;
    y += x;     
            }       
    result[counter] = y;
    counter++; 
    y = "";     
        }
        for (int t = 0; t < result.length; t++)
            {   
        System.out.println(result[t]);      
            }
return result;
}

public static void reverseResult(String[] y) //Attempt at code for  
reversing array
{
    for (int i = y.length-1; i>=0; i--) 
{
    System.out.print(y[i]+" ");     
}
}

public static int binToDecimal (){}

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException //main
{
    readFromFile();
hexToBinary();   
binToDecimal();
}

}
```

Expected outputs after conversion:

```
222494130093 -- 13651280301 -- 109200469952 -- 144419127296 -- 68935151610 -- 1046559453099 -- 178793607937 -- 252276832956
```

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: *"convert to decimal `int` variable"* This is where you get it wrong. There is no such thing as a **decimal** `int` value, since a Java `int` is always a 32-bit [two's complement binary value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Convert the hex string to an `int` value and you're done. Don't convert hex string to binary *string*. --- As for how to convert hex string to `int` value, without using the built-in `parseInt` method, search the web. You'll find lots of solutions there.

Answer (score 0):

After reversing every String in result:

```
public static int binToDecimal (){
    for(String bin:result){
        int dec=0;
        for(int i=0;i<bin.length;i++){
          dec+=Math.pow(2,i)*(bin.charAt(i)-'0');
        }
        println("" + dec);
    }
}
```

With "if" statement as you mentioned it:

```
 public static int binToDecimal (){
    for(String bin:result){
        int dec=0;
        for(int i=0;i<bin.length;i++){
          if('1' == bin.charAt(i)){
              dec+=Math.pow(2,i);
          }
        }
        println("" + dec);
    }
}
```